# Linux won't start after BIOS and packages update

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi, bios

On my  Dell HP OMEN I have dual boot for Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. Three days ago I performed a BIOS update as suggested by the system. Two days ago I performed an update of the packages as suggested by the Ubuntu package manager and everything seemed OKy. Yesterday when I started my computer I found that I couldn't boot into Ubuntu. Basically I get a series of previously unknown warning messages.

[image]

After some time the system gets me back to the boot screen. It happens the same if I try to boot into Ubuntu using Recovery mode.

This behavior happens only with Ubuntu. When I boot into Windows everything works just fine. Is there a way I can access the files in the Linux partition?

Comment: What does back to the boot page mean?

Comment: The errors are pretty common and non-fatal.  You might just have a video problem, or some Uefi setting got changed back to default -- recheck them.

Comment: I checked them but nothing seems off. Secure boot is disabled, etc...

If I reboot from the recovery mode I can get to open the ubuntu partition, If I try to start ubuntu using a flashed drive or using grub I cannot

Comment: @David basically I come back to the grub menu

Comment: If you get grub menu & can boot recovery mode, then it is not a boot issue. Probably a video issue or something else after start of boot. What video card/chip & how did you install video driver? From Ubuntu repository? If you installed directly from vendor then that is the issue.

Comment: @oldfred I'm using a Nvidia RTX3070, I installed the video drivers using ubuntu package manager

Comment: When you boot recovery mode, you see the boot process, does it show any errors? At terminal after recovery mode boot, what does this show? `sudo grep -Ei 'warn|error' /var/log/*g` I get multiple warnings that do not matter, but each line should be reviewed. Some are just an entry where warnings are mentioned and not an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the video drivers. I needed to remove all the drivers from the computer using  `sudo apt remove cuda && sudo apt remove "nvidia*" && sudo apt autoremove` then downloading and installing the right one using the "Additional Drivers" program on Ubuntu.